# Clear the contents of a window and replace them with new contents?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Is there a command/function in Python to erase the contents of a `Tk()` (window) and re-use the frame within which the window is inside?

I want to ask a user for input, then erase the labels/buttons in the window, and set up new labels/buttons inside the same window.

Also how do I create a list of labels with which to loop through and add to a `Tk()` window?

Comment: also how do I create a list of labels with which to loop through and add to a Tk() window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to all the widgets, and call the `destroy()` method on each one. Or, put all of the widgets inside another frame and destroy the frame -- destroying a frame will automatically destroy all children widgets.

I don't understand the question about creating labels in a loop. You do it like you create anything else in a loop. You can save the references in a list, though a dictionary is also convenient:

```
labels = {}
for name in ("one", "two", "three"):
    labels[name] = tk.Label(..., text=name)
    labels[name].pack(...)
```